# Is there any way to get Math.random to return an integer?

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I'm working on a Bubblesort that's supposed to take a random array of numbers and return them but I keep getting a 'possible loss of precision' error when compiling that tells me Math.random is returning a double and I need an integer. How can I covert this?

```
 public class Bubblesort {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create an int array we want to sort using bubble sort algorithm
    int intArray[] = new int [Math.random()*100];
```

Here's my code just in case.

Edit: There was more code involved that I didn't think I would need to include. I tried casting but System.out.println isn't working now.

Rest of the code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create an int array we want to sort using bubble sort algorithm
    int intArray[] = new int [(int)Math.random()*100];

    //int intArray[] = new int [100];

    //print array before sorting using bubble sort algorithm
    System.out.println("Array Before Bubble Sort");
    for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++){
      System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
    }

    //sort an array using bubble sort algorithm
    bubbleSort(intArray);

    System.out.println("");

    //print array after sorting using bubble sort algorithm
    System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");
    for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++){
      System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
    }
```

Comment: just add a cast (int)

Comment: just use the Random class:
Random  r = new Random(); 
int element = r.nextInt();

Comment: -1 simply for using bubblesort :)

Comment: That's a real dick move... And I'll have you know I'm being forced to do it for school.

Answer (score 6):

**Don't** forget to enclose it in the parenthesis before downcast to `int` otherwise it will converted to zero always because [Math.random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) returns a `double` value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

```
int intArray[] = new int [(int)(Math.random()*100)];
```

Comment: Or use `Random.nextInt()` for rather more pleasant code...

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree and that is already answered by nickb

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to type casting, you could just use [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) instead:

```
Random r = new Random();
int retval = r.nextInt(100);
```

Comment: Ideally show `r.nextInt(100)` to match the OP's sample requirement.

Comment: Great point, updated.

Answer (score 3):

Use java.util.Random, with [nextInt(int n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29)

```
Random random = new Random()
int intArray[] = new int [random.nextInt(100)];
```

From the Random javadoc for `nextInt(int n)`:

*Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.*

Answer (score 2):

You can type cast

```
int intArray[] = new int [(int)(Math.random()*100)];
```

Comment: That's wrong. it will return zero because `Math.random()` is downcast to int and it will become zero.

Comment: @Braj :) it seams like you have done the same thing.

Comment: yes I have experienced it before.

Comment: @braj I did not executed, by looking the question, I was sure that this can be simply done using type casting. Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called casting for that.

```
new int [(int) Math.random()*100];
```

It converts the return value into the data type used in the casting method.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
int randomWithRange(int min, int max){

       int range = (max - min) + 1;     
       return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification: You are creating an array with random length and not random values. Is this intended?

if not:

```
int intArray[] = new int [somesize];
for(int i=0;i<intArrey.length();i++)
{
  intArrey[i]= (int)(Math.random()*100);
}
```

Comment: I think it very much provides a solution to his question. The array elements are never initialized so I think he mixed up creating an array and initializing its values.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper If you would use a different way of order, I think there would be not problem.

Answer (score -1):

The right way to create a random integer i is:

```
Double d = Math.random()*100;
int i = d.intValue();
```